# install font on reportserver

Tags: fonts, reportserver

For a specific project I need to use 2 non-default fonts. In Jaspersoft Studio everything works fine. In Crystal Reports everything works fine and in Birt everything works fine. But when executing the report, I don't get the specified fonts to show.

How should you install the font in reportserver?

Answer (score 1):

if you mean the reportserver on http://www.reportserver.net, please check here:

https://forum.reportserver.net/viewtopic.php?id=705
https://forum.reportserver.net/viewtopic.php?id=768

"I changed the font to DejaVu and now Ubuntu is able to display the fonts properly."

Regards,
Eduardo

Comment: Hi Eduardo, Thanks for the link. But it doesn't explain which steps to take. I'm designing in Jaspersoft studio and deploying to reportserver (yes reportserver.net). I need to embed the fonts somehow.